# How to reflect order changes in a WPF listbox

Tags: wpf, binding, caliburn.micro

I have (what I feel to be) a very simple scenario that I can't seem to figure out. I've looked around here (ie. StackOverflow.com) for a solution, but can't seem to find anybody with my exact problem. I'm not sorting my listbox on a criteria; I simply want my listbox to reflect the order of the items in my collection.

I'm using Caliburn.Micro to bind an underlying collection to a WPF ListBox. I simply want to be able to allow the user to move items up and down the list using buttons that I've provided. The functionality works great! However, the ListBox will not reflect the new collection's order.

Here is a simple ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
  private readonly IObservableCollection<SimpleItem> _items;
  private SimpleItem _selectedItem;

  public MyViewModel()
  {
    _items = new BindableCollection<SimpleItems>();
    _items.Add(new SimpleItem("Item 1"));
    _items.Add(new SimpleItem("Item 2"));
    _items.Add(new SimpleItem("Item 3"));
  }
  public IObservableCollection<SimpleItem> Items
  {
    get { return _items; }
  }

  public SimpleItem SelectedItem
  {
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
      _selectedItem = value;
      NotifyOfPropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Xaml that binds to my ViewModel (again, using Caliburn.Micro):

```
<ListBox x:Name="Items">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The results display the items in my ListBox perfectly:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

Now, assume the user wants to move `Item 2` above `Item 1`. They select `Item 2`, and then click a button named `MoveUp`. I have a method in my ViewModel called MoveUp() that does the following logic (simplified for brevity):

```
public void MoveUp()
{
  var item = SelectedItem;
  var index = Items.IndexOf(item);

  Items.Remove(item);
  Items.Insert(index - 1, item);

  SelectedItem = item;
}
```

Unfortunately, the ListBox does not reflect the new order... What is the best way to tell the view that the listbox to refresh the display *without* resorting to the code-behind?

### UPDATE: July 20, 2011

I found the problem. The problem was that my collection of SimpleItems was actually a subset of a parent 'SimpleItem'. Therefore, when the user clicked on 'MoveUp', I would do a lookup on the parent SimpleItem and reference it's children directly. The problem was that the children were not bound to the IObservableCollection instance. I had to change my logic to find the observable collection instead and it works now! Thank you @devdigital for your help!

-= Luc

Comment: This should work fine, apart from a null check on SelectedItem in MoveUp(). Do you have the code for SimpleItem?

Comment: @devdigital - My solution is not bound to 'SimpleItem', it was just used as an example for this site. However, my object is just a POCO. I am not sure what I could be missing. The Xaml was directly extracted from my View. I do a check for null, but in my simple example, this is all that happens... Thanks for any additional help.

Comment: There must be something slightly different in your production code than the sample code you've provided here. I assume when you say 'the ListBox does not reflect the new order', the original 1, 2, 3 order is preserved?

Comment: You are correct. I created a brain-dead simple example with just the above code and it works. This makes me realize that I have something else going on. Thanks again! I'll be sure to post my findings when I find my bug. Thanks again! +1

Comment: Derrrrrr... I found my problem! My 'SimpleItem' wasn't so simple after all. :) My listbox displayed items from my 'IObservableCollection', but the list that I manipulate under the 'MoveUp' does some intense lookup logic and ultimately references the raw collection that I used to populate the IObservableCollection with. Now I need to rework my logic to use the interacting collection instead... Thanks again for your help. You clarified that things "should be working" and that I wasn't missing a magic setting. :) -- Luc

Comment: @devdigital - Feel free to post your initial comment as an 'Answer' and I'll mark it as the accepted answer if you wish. Even though it was nothing more than a smack on the back of my head, it was exactly what I needed. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If items are getting added and removed from your collection, and your binding is set up correctly, the updates in the view should be automatic.

Have you set breakpoints in the MoveUp method to ensure that anything is actually happening there?  I would make sure SelectedItem is bound properly (you don't show this binding in your code) and is not null when it is accessed.  I would also comment out the line that does the Insert and ensure that the Remove call actually causes your view to update properly.

Comment: SelectedItem is bound by convention by Caliburn.Micro